# reading or converting to file -byte[] array wrong

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

my name Is Omer and I'm a student.
In my project I had to upload  videos to database and also read them from the database.
I'm using OLE object field to store byte[]array.
But IDK why I Cant convert it back to file.
I don't know if my problem is in the inserting from the database or in the selecting.
my Inserting code:

```
string username = RegisterFunctions.getUsername(Session["userInfo"]);
        string heroName = Hero.Text;
        VideoService vid = new VideoService();
        string path = vid.SaveFileInFoder(myUpload.PostedFile, "potg", Server);
        byte[] videoBy = vid.ConvertFileToByte(path);
        vid.UploadVideo(heroName,username,videoBy);
```

SaveFileInFoder:

```
public  string SaveFileInFoder(HttpPostedFile file, string folder, HttpServerUtility Server)
    {
        string location;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            location = Server.MapPath(folder) + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            try
            {
                file.SaveAs(location);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                location = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            location = null;
        }

        return location;
    }
```

UploadVideo:

```
public void UploadVideo(string hero, string username , byte[] file)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Connect.GetConnectionString());
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            string sql = "Insert Into videos(username, hero, file) Values('"+username+"','"+hero+"','"+file+"') ";
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

the selecting part:

```
DataTable table = VideoService.SelectVideos();
        videoLength = table.Rows.Count.ToString();
        string path = Server.MapPath("/potg");
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            videoList += "var video1 = new video('" + table.Rows[i]["hero"] + "'," 
                + table.Rows[i]["videoid"] + ",'" + table.Rows[i]["username"] + "','" +
                table.Rows[i]["rating"] + "');" + "videos[" + i + "] = video1;";

            File.WriteAllBytes(path + "\\" + table.Rows[i]["videoid"] + ".mp4", (byte[])table.Rows[i]["file"]);
        
        }
```

Comment: Never to `throw ex`; where `ex` is a caught exception. You'll lose your stack trace. Just do `throw;` which will preserve the stack trace. Then again, if the only thing you do in your catch block is throw, there's not much point to having a try catch, and you can ditch the whole thing.

Comment: ok, done. what about my real que?

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to? Is it Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: IM using Access id this what you mean.

Comment: Your SQL statement for inserting the file is just concatenating strings. Which means your byte[] is going to have its ToString() method invoked to get a string representation of the byte array, and that's just going to be the type name, it won't contain your byte information. Instead, you should use parameterized queries to insert the data instead of string concatenation. This also has the advantage of protecting you from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: ok thanks- where do I add the parametrs?         string command = "INSERT INTO videos (hero, file,username) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();// פעולה בונה את הפרמטרים
            parameters.Add("@hero", hero);//מכניב פרמטר hero לטבלה
            parameters.Add("@file", file);//מכניס את הסרטון לטבלה
            parameters.Add("@username", username);
            
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(command, conn);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Dispose();

Comment: Please be clear and do not mix Hebrew and English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity I am saving file data as VarBinary(MAX) in the table.
For big files ( bigger than ~1MB) you probably will use BLOB or FileStream.

[File Stream Storage SQL 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/hh461480(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Simple Get File method : (omitting validation and try ,catch)

```
public byte[] GetVideo(string movieName)
    {
        byte[] file;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(string.Format(@"C:\Users\Data\Videos\{0}.mp4", movieName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }

        return file;
    }
```

Save Data in DB (try avoiding using SQL reserved word for column names, like 'file')

```
    public void UploadVideo(string hero, string username, byte[] file)
    {
        // OleDbConnection implements IDisposable
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Connect.GetConnectionString()))
        {

            conn.Open();

            // DbCommand implements IDisposable
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                // command with placeholders in order to prevent sql injection
                // NOTE : OleDb does not support named parameters, so ? symbol is used here
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into videos ([username], [hero], [movieFile]) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

                // add parameters
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hero", hero);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", file);
                
                // execute
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Get Data from DB and save as MP4 file

```
public void SaveVideos(string videoName)
    {
        DataTable table = VideoService.SelectVideos();
        string path =string.Format(@"C:\Users\Data\Videos\{0}.mp4",videoName);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //...
            //...
            //...
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, (byte[])table.Rows[i]["movieFile"]);
        }
    }
```